# Divider for both Light and Dark theme in PopupMenu

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a PopupMenu attached with a button present in `toolbar` and the code looks something like this:

```
val popup = PopupMenu(this, view)
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_button)
MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(popup.menu, true)
popup.show()
```

It shows a divider between the menu groups. But the problem is, I am unable to style the color of the divider for both light and dark theme.

Here is my styles.xml looks like:

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>

<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/some_color</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have also tried to have a separate style for PopupMenu. here is the style:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopup</item>

<style name="MyPopup" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/come_color</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Since nothing was working, I have even tried to have a dropdown style as below:

```
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListStyle</item>

<style name="DropDownListStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Few also suggested to try with `ContextThemeWrapper`, so I tried even that:

```
  val wrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.DropDownListStyle)
  val popup = PopupMenu(wrapper, optionsMenuActions)
  popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
  popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_pay_now)
  MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(popup.menu, true)
  popup.show()
```

Here is the sample screenshot:
[image]

And the menu_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_save_invoice"
            android:title="item1"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_subtotal_unlock"
            android:title="item2"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_cancel_transaction"
            android:title="item3"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm trying same thing but couldn't find anything